# Can anyone tell me about the onboard accelerometer of LightBlue Bean?

Tags: accelerometer

I would like to know the specs of the accelerometer used on a LightBlue Bean before buying one, but I couldn't find any info online. Anybody has an idea?

Comment: They seem to have a web site. How about asking on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reference to the [accelerometer datasheet](http://ae-bst.resource.bosch.com/media/products/dokumente/bma250/bst-bma250-ds002-05.pdf) from the [Arduino Reference page](http://legacy.punchthrough.com/bean/the-arduino-reference/accelerationreading/)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know the specs of the accelerometer used on a LightBlue Bean before buying one, but I couldn't find any info online. Anybody has an idea?

Start by checking the Adafruit [LightBlue Bean](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2732) product description. There you can find a link to the [schematics and board layout](https://www.adafruit.com/images/product-files/2732/Bean_revE_board_export.pdf). On page two there is accelerometer, a BMA250 just as @Jason links to.

That took "30 seconds" web search plus writing this answer :)

Cheers!